# bash script doesn't work through crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running a bash script that transfers files to my AWS bucket.If i run the bash script through my terminal it works fine (via ./myBash.sh). 
However I put it in my crontab but there it doesn't work.This is my bash script

> #!/bin/bash
>
> s3cmd put /home/anonymous/commLogs.txt s3://myBucket/
>
> echo  transfer completed
>
> echo now listing files in the s3 bucket
>
> s3cmd ls s3://myBucket/
>
> echo check

And this is my crontab-

> SHELL=/bin/sh
>
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
>
> 46 13 * * * /bin/bash myBash.sh

And here is a list of things i have aready tried -

1)tried running the crontab with a node app to test whether crontab was working(the answer was yes)

2)tried running the crontab without the SHELL and PATH

3)Tried running the bash script from cron using sudo (46 13 * * * sudo myBash.sh)

4)tried running the bash without the /bin/bash

5) Searched many sites on the net for an answer without satisfactory results

Can anyone help me with what the problem may be?(I am running Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Did you output the stdout of the script from the cron  to a file what was the contents of that file? (`46 13 * * * /bin/bash myBash.sh > /home/anonymous/cron_out.txt`)

Comment: This script was just to test whether that crontab was executing the bash or not..so the contents of the txt file were just "abcdefgh"

Comment: So you did not. And did you exclude the path to your script in the cron like above?

Comment: The bash script is the /bin folder

Comment: If it is in the path, give it execution rights with `chmod` and remove the `/bin/bash` part from your `crontab`, ie. `46 13 * * * myBash.sh`.

Comment: Ok i just output the stdout of the script and it worked fine.The contents of all echos got printed to a file called cron_out.txt.But the files didnt get transferred to the aws bucket

Comment: Hey thanks for your help....I couldn't find a definite solution to this problem but i am looking at some alternatives.I found a node wrapper for s3 so i don't have to worry about crontab. So now the automated file transfer is being taken care of through node.js.....Again thanks for your help again

Comment: Change the name of script to just myBash (without extension) and see whether that makes a difference.

Comment: Check your journal/message files for details of cron execution and what may be going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

After a long time getting the same error, I just did this :

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin


* * * * * /bin/bash /home/joaovitordeon/Documentos/test.sh
```

Comment: This answers should be accepted as the issue was that the script path wasn't complete.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this post.
I was having same problem and reason was crontab was running under root user and s3cmd was configured under ubuntu user.
so need to copy .s3cfg to root

```
cp -i /home/ubuntu/.s3cfg /root/.s3cfg
```